# MIPS findSum function

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to implement the findSum function using MIPS assembly. It gives the wrong sum since the second element, and I don't know why. The following is the code:

```
    .data
myArray:            .word 36 56 8 99 54 3 2 9 54 13
myArraySize:        .word 10
sumMsg:         .asciiz "\nThe sum is "
```

```
    .text
    .globl main_
main_:

        jal findSum     #Call the procedure to find the sum of myArray
        la $a0, sumMsg      #Output the message
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        addi $a0, $s0, 0            #Output the result
        li $v0, 1
        syscall
```

```
findSum:    
        lw $t3, myArraySize # t3 is array size
        addi $a0, $0, 0 # a0 is sum, set it to 0
        addi $t0, $0, 0 # t0 is count, set it to 0

        lw $t1, myArray # t1 is array element

foreach:    add $a0, $a0, $t1 # update sum to sum+thisElement
        addi $t1, $t1, 4 # move to next element
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 # count += 1

        slt $t2, $t0, $t3
        bne $t2, $zero, foreach # if this one is not last one, do for next one

        addi $s0, $a0, 0 # store sum to s0

        jr $ra
```

Comment: You're not loading anything from `myArray` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findSum:    
        addi $t0, $0, 0 # t0 is sum, set to 0
        addi $t1, $0, 0 # t1 is count, set to 0
        addi $t2, $0, 0 # t2 is temp, set to 0
        addi $t3, $0, 10 # t3 is 10
        la $a0, myArray # a0 is array element
foreach:
        lw $t2, 0($a0) # save this element in t2
        add $t0, $t0, $t2 # update sum
        addi $t1, $t1, 1 # update count
        addi $a0, $a0, 4 # move to next element

        slt $t4, $t1, $t3 # if count < 10, store result in t4
        bne $t4, $0, foreach



        addi $s0, $0, 0 # init s0 to 0
        addi $s0, $t0, 0 # store sum to s0
        addi $v0, $t0, 0 # store sum to v0

        jr $ra
```